# Speed up Min/Max operation on postgres with index for IN operator query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I would like to optimize the following query in postgres

```
SELECT(MIN("products"."shipping") AS minimal FROM "products" WHERE "products"."tag_id" IN (?)
```

with an index like

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON products (tag_id, shipping DESC);
```

Unfortunately this one is only used when it's just one tag. Almost alwayst it is queried for a handful of tags at the same time, but then postgres uses the index `products (shipping DESC)` which is quite slow. 
What could I do to speed up my query?

Comment: Have you tried: `SELECT(MIN(minimal) AS minimal FROM ( SELECT(MIN("products"."shipping") AS minimal FROM "products" WHERE "products"."tag_id" IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) GROUP BY "tag_id" ) some_alias` ?

Comment: Great! This seems to speed things up on my data :) You can also post as an answer and I can give you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out (please see comments), that this query:

```
SELECT MIN(minimal) AS minimal 
FROM ( 
  SELECT  MIN("products"."shipping") AS minimal 
  FROM "products" 
  WHERE "products"."tag_id" IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
  GROUP BY "tag_id" 
) some_alias
```

is able to deceive PostgreSQL in such a way, that it performs better because, as I guess, it uses the index in this case.